# I'm working on Sumsub SDK implementation, getting an error with SNSErrorHandler class

Tags: android

I'm working on Sumsub SDK implementation, getting an error with SNSErrorHandler class. It's saying to define SNSAppActivity in Android Manifest.xml file.

```
private void launchSdk(String accessToken, TokenExpirationHandler tokenUpdater) {//accessToken is coming from server (end pole) side.

    List<SNSModule> modules = Arrays.asList(new SNSProoface());
    Context applicationContext = context.getApplicationContext();

    SNSErrorHandler errorHandler = e -> {//Here I am getting error, It's saying to define SNSAppActivity in your Manifest.xml file
        Timber.d("The SDK throws an exception. Exception: %s", e);

        if (e instanceof SNSException.Api) {
            Timber.d("Api exception. %s", ((SNSException.Api) e).getDescription());
        } else if (e instanceof SNSException.Network) {
            Timber.d(e, "Network exception.");
        } else if (e instanceof SNSException.Unknown) {
            Timber.d(e, "Unknown exception.");
        }
        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "The SDK throws an exception. Exception: " + e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    };

    SNSStateChangedHandler stateChangedHandler = (previousState, currentState) -> {

        Timber.d("The SDK state was changed: " + previousState + " -> " + currentState);

        if (currentState instanceof SNSSDKState.Ready) {
            Timber.d("SDK is ready");
            parseStatus(currentState);
        } else if (currentState instanceof SNSSDKState.Failed.Unauthorized) {
            Timber.e(((SNSSDKState.Failed.Unauthorized) currentState).getException(), "Invalid token or a token can't be refreshed by the SDK. Please, check your token expiration handler");
            parseStatus(currentState);

        } else if (currentState instanceof SNSSDKState.Failed.Unknown) {
            Timber.e(((SNSSDKState.Failed.Unknown) currentState).getException(), "Unknown error");
            parseStatus(currentState);
        } else if (currentState instanceof SNSSDKState.Initial) {
            Timber.d("No verification steps are passed yet");
            parseStatus(currentState);

        } else if (currentState instanceof SNSSDKState.Incomplete) {
            Timber.d("Some but not all verification steps are passed over");
            parseStatus(currentState);
        } else if (currentState instanceof SNSSDKState.Pending) {
            Timber.d("Verification is in pending state");
            parseStatus(currentState);

        } else if (currentState instanceof SNSSDKState.FinallyRejected) {
            Timber.d("Applicant has been finally rejected");
            parseStatus(currentState);
        } else if (currentState instanceof SNSSDKState.TemporarilyDeclined) {
            Timber.d("Applicant has been declined temporarily");
            parseStatus(currentState);

        } else if (currentState instanceof SNSSDKState.Approved) {
            Timber.d("Applicant has been approved");
            parseStatus(currentState);
        }

        if (currentState instanceof SNSSDKState.ActionCompleted) {
            SNSSDKState.ActionCompleted actionState = (SNSSDKState.ActionCompleted) currentState;
            String actionId = actionState.getActionId();
            FlowActionType type = actionState.getType();
            String answer = actionState.getAnswer();
            Map<String, Object> payload = actionState.getPayload();
        }
    };

    SNSCompleteHandler completeHandler = (result, state) -> {
        Timber.d("The SDK is finished. Result: " + result + " , State: " + state);
        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "The SDK is finished. Result: " + result + ", State: " + state, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        if (result instanceof SNSCompletionResult.SuccessTermination) {
            Timber.d(result.toString());
        } else if (result instanceof SNSCompletionResult.AbnormalTermination) {
            Timber.d(((SNSCompletionResult.AbnormalTermination) result).getException());
        }
    };

    SNSActionResultHandler actionResultHandler = (actionId, actionType, answer, allowContinuing) -> {
        Timber.d("Action Result: actionId: " + actionId + ", answer: " + answer);
        return SNSActionResult.Continue;
    };

    SNSEventHandler eventHandler = snsEvent -> {
        if (snsEvent instanceof SNSEvent.SNSEventStepInitiated) {
            Timber.d("onEvent: step initiated");
        } else if (snsEvent instanceof SNSEvent.SNSEventStepCompleted) {
            Timber.d("onEvent: step completed");
        }
    };

    SNSSupportItem supportItem = new SNSSupportItem(
            R.string.sns_support_title,
            R.string.sns_support_subtitle,
            SNSSupportItem.Type.Email, "support@company.com", null,
            SNSIconHandler.SNSCommonIcons.MAIL.getImageName(), null);

    try {

        SNSMobileSDK.SDK snsSdk = new SNSMobileSDK.Builder(context)
                .withBaseUrl(apiUrl)
                .withAccessToken(accessToken, tokenUpdater)
                .withDebug(true)
                .withModules(modules)
                .withCompleteHandler(completeHandler)
                .withErrorHandler(errorHandler)
                .withStateChangedHandler(stateChangedHandler)
                .withActionResultHandler(actionResultHandler)
                .withEventHandler(eventHandler)
                .withSupportItems(Collections.singletonList(supportItem))
                .withConf(new SNSInitConfig("support@gmail.com", "+910000000000", null))
                .build();

        snsSdk.launch();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Timber.e(e);
    }
    showProgress(false);

}
```